# How to trigger a delayed task posted to a ScheduledExecutorService with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I want to do an integration test with Robolectric where I need to check the state of my app after a certain delayed task executed by a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Let's say I execute my task regularly with this code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService delayedExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
delayedExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(storeStateTask, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In my robolectric test I tried executing combinations of the following code to advance the internal time or execute pending tasks:

```
Robolectric.getBackgroundThreadScheduler().advanceBy(61, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().advanceBy(61, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler();
Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();
shadowOf(context.getMainLooper()).idle();
```

None of this led to an execution the scheduled task. Any ideas how to force/control the execution of my scheduled task without adding a helper method in my production code?

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric doesn't seem to support ScheduledExecutorService. Try to use RoboExecutorService.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however I believe that would require that I will be able to inject a mocked (RoboExecutorService) executor into my code. So I would need to change the production code for that, or do some ugly reflection magic.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not related to roboeletric but you can use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(1, SECONDS)` or longer timeout as necessary as this will block and execute tasks waiting for execution after that you can see results and continue test:

I did it like this in my test:

```
@Test
fun testFileJsonStore() {
    val store = CSFileJsonStore(context, "file")
    val property: StoreTypesTestData by store.property("property")
    assertEquals(5, property.int)

    property.string = "new value"
    property.int = 123
    property.jsonObject.lateString = "new value"
    executor.awaitTermination(1, SECONDS)
    assertEquals(
        """{"property":{"key1":"new value","key2":123,"key3":{"lateStringId":"new value"}}}""",
        store.file.readString())

    val store2: CSStore = CSFileJsonStore(context, "file")
    val property2: StoreTypesTestData by store2.property("property")
    assertEquals("new value", property2.string)
    assertEquals(123, property2.int)
    assertEquals("new value", property2.jsonObject.lateString)
}
```